# Try-with-resources in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, try-with-resources

When I tried to write an equivalent of a Java [`try`-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement in Kotlin, it didn't work for me.

I tried different variations of the following:

```
try (writer = OutputStreamWriter(r.getOutputStream())) {
    // ...
}
```

But neither works. Does anyone know what should be used instead?

Apparently Kotlin grammar [doesn't include](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html) such a construct, but maybe I'm missing something. It defines the grammar for a `try` block as follows:

```
try : "try" block catchBlock* finallyBlock?;
```

Answer (score 285, accepted):

There is a [`use`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) function in kotlin-stdlib ([src](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/885d99068c35ac7c959a4db29c3e1d543a7459b6/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/io/Closeable.kt#L21)).

How to use it:

```
OutputStreamWriter(r.getOutputStream()).use {
    // `it` is your OutputStreamWriter
    it.write('a')
}
```

Comment: I love extension methods so much. So many things you can do and no need for additional language features.

Comment: Adding to this, there is actually an extension property to obtain an `OutputStreamWriter` as well: `r.outputStream.writer.use { ... }`

Comment: Link to the reference doc that demonstrates the `use` extension: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#java-7s-try-with-resources

Comment: How can I use multi "use" in a better way? 
```FileOutputStream(into).use {
            val mergingStream = BufferedOutputStream(it).use {

            }

        }
```

Comment: What about flushing? should I flush OutputStream at the end of use block?

Comment: what about for multi streams? I.e, stdout and stderr ? Java try resource allows multiple streams.

Comment: Sad this is not multiplatform, but only for JVM, so don't use it if your project is multiplatform [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html)

Answer (score 77):

#### TL;DR: No special syntax, just a function

Kotlin, as opposed to Java, does not have a special syntax for this. Instead, *try-with-resources*, is offered as the standard library function `use`.

```
FileInputStream("filename").use { fis -> //or implicit `it`
   //use stream here
}
```

---

#### The `use` implementations

```
@InlineOnly
public inline fun <T : Closeable?, R> T.use(block: (T) -> R): R {
    var closed = false
    try {
        return block(this)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        closed = true
        try {
            this?.close()
        } catch (closeException: Exception) {
        }
        throw e
    } finally {
        if (!closed) {
            this?.close()
        }
    }
}
```

This function is defined as a generic extension on all `Closeable?` types. `Closeable` is Java's [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html#suppressed-exceptions) that allows *try-with-resources* as of Java [SE7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html).
The function *takes* a function literal `block` which gets executed in a `try`. Same as with *try-with-resources* in Java, the `Closeable` gets **closed** in a `finally`.

Also failures happening inside `block` lead to `close` executions, where possible exceptions are literally "suppressed" by just ignoring them. *This* is different from *try-with-resources*, because such exceptions can be requested in [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html#suppressed-exceptions)‘s solution.

#### How to use it

The `use` extension is available on any `Closeable` type, i.e. streams, readers and so on.

```
FileInputStream("filename").use {
   //use your stream by referring to `it` or explicitly give a name.
}
```

The part in curly brackets is what becomes `block` in `use` (a lambda is passed as an argument here). After the block is done, you can be sure that `FileInputStream` has been closed.

Comment: What about multiple resources?

Answer (score 16):

**Edit**: The following response is still valid for Kotlin 1.0.x. For Kotlin 1.1, there is support a standard library that targets Java 8 to support closable resource pattern.

For other classes that do not support the "use" function, I have done the following homemade try-with-resources:

```
package info.macias.kotlin

inline fun <T:AutoCloseable,R> trywr(closeable: T, block: (T) -> R): R {
    try {
        return block(closeable);
    } finally {
        closeable.close()
    }
}
```

Then you can use it the following way:

```
fun countEvents(sc: EventSearchCriteria?): Long {
    return trywr(connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event")) {
        var rs = it.executeQuery()
        rs.next()
        rs.getLong(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not deal properly with exceptions thrown from the finally clause, which is one of the reasons try-with-resources was added to Java. This is just a simple `try/finally` block

Answer (score 2):

I will highly recommend to use AutoCloseable for classes.

> AutoCloseable object is called automatically when exiting a
> try-with-resources block for which the object has been declared in the
> resource specification header.

Example:

```
class Resource : AutoCloseable {
    fun op1() = println("op1")
    override fun close() = println("close up.")
}
```

in main function:

```
Resource().use {
    it.op1()
}
```

Output:

```
> op1
close up.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this StackOverflow post is near the top of the current search results for "kotlin closeable example," and yet none of the other answers (nor the official docs) clearly explain how to extend `Closeable` (a.k.a. `java.io.Closeable`), I thought I'd add an example of how to make your own class that extends `Closeable`. It goes like this:

```
import java.io.Closeable

class MyServer : Closeable {
    override fun close() {
        println("hello world")
    }
}
```

And then to use it:

```
fun main() {
    val s = MyServer()
    s.use {
        println("begin")
    }
    println("end")
}
```

See this example in the Kotlin Playground [here](https://pl.kotl.in/wgow-8-0O).