# Why doesn't Kotlin require try and catch explicitly

Tags: java, exception, kotlin

For example:

```
FileOutputStream("file")
```

would compile in Kotlin, but in Java it would give a compiler error. Why?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#checked-exceptions

Comment: Kotlin has no checked exceptions, as in C# and other languages

Comment: The aim of Kotlin creators is to make _popular_ language. So they add a bunch of syntactical sugar and sacrifice everything that can confuse beginner. And checked exceptions often annoys beginners That's why.

Comment: Kotlin tries to get rid of boilerplate code whenever possible

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin does away with Java's checked exceptions. Exceptions checked at compile time and declared in method signatures, though familiar to Java developers, are widely considered a failed experiment [outside](http://radio-weblogs.com/0122027/stories/2003/04/01/JavasCheckedExceptionsWereAMistake.html) and to some degree [inside](https://dzone.com/articles/checked-exceptions-i-love-you) the Java community.

So Kotlin did away with them, and with some of the boilerplate associated with using resources (like `FileOutputStream`) with the [.use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969800/try-with-resources-in-kotlin#26979481) method shorthand for Java 7's [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: So what would be the appropriate way to handle those exceptions if i didn't know that they will occur in advance?

Comment: In the case of Java classes used in Kotlin, you can simply check the interface method signature or Javadoc. There may be some exceptions that you want to recover from and others that you want to let kill your thread. As mentioned above, `FileOutputStream(File("path")).use{ ... }` is most likely what you are looking for.

Comment: @NateVaughan If it's a Kotlin interface, it won't have any exceptions declared. And what if there is no Javadoc or it's incomplete?

Comment: @Malcolm If you really don’t trust the code, or know what exceptions it throws, you will handle any exceptions the same way you handle runtime exceptions: using catch(Exception e)

Comment: @NateVaughan Then how am I supposed to recover from them if I don't know which ones I can get? This is so-called Pokemon exception handling (catch-em-all). Catch any and very helpfully say to the user that something is wrong, but I don't know what? That's precisely the problem with exceptions in Kotlin.

Comment: @Malcolm You have exactly the same problem with libraries that throw RuntimeExceptions, have throws Exception in their method signatures, or wrap a specific exception in a generic one (e.g. KryoException). The problem as you describe it exists only with code you do not control that throws thoughtful, detailed exceptions that somehow did not make it into any documentation, which I think you'll find is very rare.

Comment: @NateVaughan Even discerning an `IOException` from `Exception` helps, there's nothing "thoughtful, detailed" in this. And exceptions can be missing from documentation for the same simple reason that the library authors don't have any compiler help when writing documentation either. Also I don't understand why this is supposed to happen only with the code you don't control. In my own code I often forget which methods can throw which exceptions either, and I'd rather have compiler tell me than writing all this stuff out by hand in comments (which you can also forget to check).

Comment: So... for the sounds of it, we need to use `.use{...}` everywhere, regardless if we need to or not, else we have to spend hours going over Java documentation to know when to use `use`... brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

It can be difficult to answer without letting some opinions interfere. I will just say that Kotlin is aimed at large software projects and give you what the Kotlin team claims regarding checked exceptions (from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html):

> **Checked Exceptions**
>
> Kotlin does not have checked exceptions. There are many reasons for
>   this, but we will provide a simple example.
>
> The following is an example interface of the JDK implemented by
>   StringBuilder class:
>
> Appendable append(CharSequence csq) throws IOException; What does this
>   signature say? It says that every time I append a string to something
>   (a StringBuilder, some kind of a log, a console, etc.) I have to catch
>   those IOExceptions. Why? Because it might be performing IO (Writer
>   also implements Appendable)… So it results into this kind of code all
>   over the place:
>
> ```
> try {
>     log.append(message)
> }
> catch (IOException e) {
>     // Must be safe
> }
> ```
>
> And this is no good, see [Effective Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/effectivejava-136174.html), Item 65: *Don't ignore
>   exceptions.*
>
> Bruce Eckel says in [Does Java need Checked Exceptions?](http://www.mindview.net/Etc/Discussions/CheckedExceptions):
>
> > Examination of small programs leads to the conclusion that requiring
> >     exception specifications could both enhance developer productivity and
> >     enhance code quality, but experience with large software projects
> >     suggests a different result – decreased productivity and little or no
> >     increase in code quality.
>
> Other citations of this sort:
>
> [Java's checked exceptions were a mistake](http://radio-weblogs.com/0122027/stories/2003/04/01/JavasCheckedExceptionsWereAMistake.html) (Rod Waldhoff)
>
> [The Trouble with Checked Exceptions](http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html) (Anders Hejlsberg)